# Entity Framework Update-Database not showing DB in App_Data folder

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been working on ASP .Net Webforms for some time now. But, recently I decided to learn MVC. I am taking a course by Mosh Hamedani. The thing is, I was following his course and his Code-First approach. I followed every bit of it, step by step. But when I created my first migration and tried to update-database for the first time, I got a network related or instance-related error. I knew it had something to do with SQL server. So, I went to web.config and added my SQL server name in the data source. After that I tried to run update-database and this time it did not give the error. But the database in the course was created in the app-data folder but mine did not appear there. Instead, it appeared in my SQL management studio. What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please explain? I am really new to MVC and I am unable to understand the reason behind this. Please, if anyone can help me or guide me through this, I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud have something like this in your `App.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyContext"
           connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\.\SharedLocal;Initial Catalog=OutageContext; Integrated Security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Post some more information here, if that does not work.

Comment: I dont have app.config file. I have a web.config file, and following I found following code in it that was similar to your answer. What should I edit in this?
<br>
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Vidly 2-20210321063409.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-Vidly 2-20210321063409&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Now I doubt that your problem is linked with the connection string, but you can try one above instead of that one in your web.config

Comment: Thanks for helping. I had to add my sql server name in the data source of my web.config file. The problem I was unable to see the database in app_data folder was that I was looking in solution explorer and I had not enabled the show all files option.